Migrate and taxonomy term: missing bundle
I'm using migrate and migrate_plus to migrate contents. I've a problem with taxonomy_terms. I'm on 10.3 core, with stable versions of all modules.
This is my xml (only with 1 item, for the example):
<response>
  <item key="0">
    <tid>17</tid>
    <uuid>37862cbe-3325-4119-a15e-7732d810b56f</uuid>
    <vocabolario>lingue</vocabolario>
    <name>italiano</name>
    <description/>
    <immagine/>
  </item>
</response>

On the drupal site I've created a vocabulary with machine name "lingue".
This is my migrate_plus.migration.termini.yml (inside the "config" directory of my custom module):
id: termini
label: 06. Termini
migration_group: ilDeposito

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - https://www.mysite.com/export/termini.json
  item_selector: /response/item
  fields:
    -
      name: tid
      selector: tid
    -
      name: name
      selector: name
    -
      name: uuid
      selector: uuid
    -
      name: vocabolario
      selector: vocabolario
    -
      name: description
      selector: description

  ids:
    tid:
      type: string

process:
  uuid: uuid
  name:
    plugin: encode
    source: name

destination:
  plugin: entity:taxonomy_term
  bundle: vocabolario

If I try to run "drush mim termini" I obtain:
[error]  Missing bundle for entity type taxonomy_term (/var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php:125)
If I try to add "vid" or "bundle" in "process" section I obtain the same error.
What's wrong? Does vocabularies has a numeric ID to use?
If I try to add a "default_bundle: lingue" option in "destination" settings, it works.
Thanks

The key in your destination: section should read default_bundle: vocabolario, but not just bundle:.

I tried it, but it doesn't work. If I use migrate-devel, the output is this:
4^ array:12 [
"tid" => "17"
"name" => "italiano"
"uuid" => "37862cbe-3325-4119-a15e-7732d810b56f"
"vocabolario" => ""
"description" => ""
Why "vocabolario" is empty?

And if I try to add a default_bundle that is not a field from xml, it works.

default_bundle is the machine name of a taxonomy vocabulary that should exist on the destination site. On a standard Drupal install, an example is the tags vocabulary. From what I see above, it seems that you have a lingue vocabulary on your site?

Yes, I've "lingue" vocabulary. The problem is that the "vocabolario" field is empty, in migrate! I've tried to create a process plugin to debug, with my ide, the value of this field. And the value is empty. Also if I try to change the name to "vid". The xml is correct and, in the whole xml, I've terms for different vocabularties, so I would have a single importer for all terms.

Ah, then, if I get it right, put default_bundle: lingue in destination: section. In your process: section, put bundle: vocabulario to map the xml field to a specific vocabulary. You have to have taxonomy vocabularies for every vocabolario variant in your xml.
